# Keep active state on links that already have class

Tags: jquery, css

I want that hover underline to stay visible when your on the specific link. I understand you could do this. But I've already added the `nombore` class to the `a href`

```
$(function () {
$(".numbers li a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(" .numbers li a").parent().addClass("active").not($(this).parent()).removeClass("active");
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ydxqt7jp/

Comment: Not clear what you want to do. Can you make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fiddle didn't have any active class, or the JS.

Have a look below for a working version

```js
$(function () {
    $(".numbers li a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".numbers li a").removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

```css
 .numbers {
     z-index: 999;
     font-size: 16px;
     font-family:'Theinhardt-Rg';
     margin-top: 50px;
     list-style-type: none;
     position: fixed;
     left: 20px;
 }
 .numbers li > a {
     color: #696969;
     text-decoration:none;
     margin-bottom:30px;
 }
 .numbers li > a:hover {
     color: #030303;
     text-decoration:none;
 }
 .slider {
     position: absolute;
     display: block;
     left: 0;
     top: 90%;
     margin: 0 auto;
     height: 3px;
     background-color: #030303;
     width: 0%;
     transition: width 0.5s ease;
 }
 .nombore {
     position: relative;
     display: inline-block;
     transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
 }
 .nombore:hover .slider {
     width: 100%;
 }
 .nombore.active {
     color: #030303;
     text-decoration: none;
 }
 .nombore.active .slider {
     width:100%;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="numbers">
    <li><a href="#/" class="nombore"><span>:/</span>        <span class="slider">
        </span></a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#modal1" class="nombore"><span>01</span> <span class="slider">
        </span></a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#modal2" class="nombore"><span>02</span> <span class="slider">
        </span></a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#modal3" class="nombore"><span>03</span> <span class="slider">
        </span></a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#modal4" class="nombore"><span>04</span> <span class="slider">
        </span></a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#modal5" class="nombore"><span>05</span> <span class="slider">
        </span></a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#modal6" class="nombore"><span>06</span> <span class="slider">
        </span></a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#modal7" class="nombore"><span>07</span> <span class="slider">
        </span></a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#modal0" class="nombore"><span>/p</span> <span class="slider">
        </span></a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That looks like it works. But when I click on a number, the a href doesn't open. Like if I press 07, #modal7 doesn't open. Nothing happens.

Comment: @user2252219 Please post a fiddle with the modals. The code you provided does not have any modals

Comment: @user2252219 have a look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/web_dever/ydxqt7jp/4/)

Comment: When you flip between modals, say `modal1` to `modal7` the active underline doesn't stick in the new modal.

Comment: @user2252219 Have a look at this [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/web_dever/ydxqt7jp/5/)

Comment: No dice. Try flipping between 01 and 06. http://imdarrien.com/#modal1 The line doesn't stay.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88534/discussion-between-pindo-and-user2252219).

Answer (score 0):

add this to your head:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and this to your style:

```
.active a .slider {
     width: 100%;
 }
```